# in xcode, a right pointing arrow character in a label looks like an icon instead of text, why? and how to fix this?

Tags: swift, uilabel, character, xcode7

As you can see in the image below, the right pointing arrow is not an image, believe it or not, it's a label !!!

[image]

```
    let triCharacter = "▶"
    labelTri1.frame = CGRectMake(200,300,50,50)
    labelTri1.text = triCharacter
    self.view.addSubview(labelTri1)
```

This is the code I use, I want the right pointing arrow to like like this in a regular label, ▶ , why XCode turned this into an image? also what is the list of characters that can be converted to images? Maybe that will be in handy some day, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Is it label or image ?

Comment: it's a label, but the strange thing it get's rendered as an image as illustrated.

Comment: Haa ok. I see now. Could you try with this "▸" I really wonder what happens :) Maybe your character represent something in iOS

Comment: @emresancaktar : so ▸ works and ▶ get's converted into an emoji, interesting.